# SSH Authentication Problem

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ssh

i'm currently trying to setup a few virtualboxes (ubuntu 15.10) to simulat a network i'm developing some software for. For this i need to setup a SSH connection, this is working, but i can login without the rsa-pubkey setup, just with the user-password from the vbox. The sshd_config file looks like it should and i cant find the problem. Is it maybe a virtualbox problem?

**edit**

my problem with the situation is, that i want the usual ssh-server setup with rsa-authentication. Right now i just can login without it and cant figure out what i have to do.

**Solution**

Ok my keyring did the autologin ofc :D i'm too stupid sometimes. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: i dont really understand why i can login my vbox without setting up the rsa-authentication and i want to know how to make a right setup.

Comment: It's unclear what is happening now and what you want.  Can you explain by revising your question to include more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create the RSA Key Pair

The first step is to create the key pair on the client machine (In your case it is your computer outside virtual box):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

### Store the Keys and Passphrase

Once you have entered the `ssh-keygen` command, you will get a few more questions:

1. Enter file in which to save the key (`/home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa`): *You can press enter here.*
2. Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):

The entire key generation process looks like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
4a:dd:0a:c6:35:4e:3f:ed:27:38:8c:74:44:4d:93:67 demo@a
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|          .oo.   |
|         .  o.E  |
|        + .  o   |
|     . = = .     |
|      = S = .    |
|     o + = +     |
|      . o + o .  |
|           . o   |
|                 |
+-----------------+
The public key is now located in /home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub The private key (identification) is now located in /home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa
```

### Copy the Public Key

Once the key pair is generated, it's time to place the public key on the virtual-box server.

You can copy the public key into the v-box's authorized_keys file.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@192.168.1.1 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Replace `192.168.1.1` with a suitable "v-box" IP address.